# Gitlab CI pipeline failed because of user not authorized

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project with a build and deploy pipeline on GitLab CI/CD. I can run it manually and also on commit but my team members in my organization cannot. They get an error: "The pipeline failed due to the user not being verified" and GitLab told them that they have to use a debit or credit card. Is there any possibility to do this another way?

I tried to create a Deploy key in settings -> repository but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings > Repository > Push Rules make sure that "Reject unverified users" is not checked.

I've had this happen before in repositories that have had a lot of team turnover. Then a new person comes on board and no one can figure out why the "new fellow" can commit.

[image: Check the Push Rules for the repository.]